# Oracle NUMBER(3) = -999 to 999 or -99 to 99 (is the sign part of the precision)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is the oracle number format precision including the sign?

Is a Oracle NUMBER(3) from -999 to 999 or from -99 to 99?

Does the sign count as a digit in the precision value?

Comment: Why not just testing?

Comment: I normally would. But I don't have access to the db, I'm just helping a colleague that is working conceptually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

number(3) means it will hold values from -999 to 999. The sign is not counted towards the precision.

eg:

```
SQL> create table numcheck(a number(3));

Table created.

SQL> insert into numcheck values (-999);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into numcheck values (999);

1 row created.

SQL> select a, vsize(a), dump(a) from numcheck;

         A   VSIZE(A) DUMP(A)
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
      -999          4 Typ=2 Len=4: 61,92,2,102
       999          3 Typ=2 Len=3: 194,10,100
```